# (PHP) Data is returning true or false all the time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to build a php website that outputs a list of movies which I am capable of doing. I am having trouble to update another table with `PDO connexion` using phpmyadmin. *I am so new to php that I am learning as I'm coding.*

I am using a `select` query to show a list of movies' title and rating. | **works fine**
I'm offering a user to add a new rating to a movie of his choice through inputs. | **output is true all the time or false all the time**

The only hint regarding my attempt to update my table is that my `if block` tells me with the code below that `$result is false`.

---

**main.php**

```
<form method="post" action="controller.php">
    <input type="number" name="data_rating" placeholder="Between 0 and 100">
    <input type="text" name="data_movie_id" placeholder="Movie's ID">
    <input type="text" name="data_comment" placeholder="Comment">

    <input type="submit" name="data_new_rating" value="Add rating">
</form>
```

**controller.php**

```php
// First if is $_POST['connexion_to_database'] with user's ID and password
else if(isset($_POST['data_new_rating']))
{
   add_rating();
}
```

**model.php**

```php
function add_rating() 
{
    $rating = $_POST['data_rating'];
    $comment= $_POST['data_comment'];
    $movieID = $_POST['data_movie_id'];

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("my connexion string");
        $output = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO rating(rating, comment, date, clientID, movieID)
                                    VALUES (:rating, :comment, :date, :clientID, :movieID)";
        $result = $output->execute(array(
                    ':rating' => $rating,
                    ':comment' => $comment,
                    ':date' => date("Y-m-d"),
                    ':clientID' => $_SESSION["id"],
                    ':movieID' => $movieID
                    ));

        if($result){
            echo "Movie rated successfully!";
        }else{
            echo "Movie has not been rated...";
        }

        $conn = null;
        // header("Location:main.php");
        // I have commented this ^ because I need to see which echo is showing for debugging purpose.
    } catch { } ...
}
```

Comment: _SMall Point_ PDO connects to a `MySQL` database and no `phpmyadmin` which is a tool written in PHP for mainitaining a MySQL database

Comment: $_POST['data_new_rating'] is always going to be null because it has no value

Comment: So which message do you see from that IF

Comment: When `$result` is false, try `var_dump($output->errorInfo());` and see if that gives you any information. (edit, forgot it was an array, not a string)

Comment: You could try changing `placeholder="Add rating"` to `value="Add rating"` as SUBMIT inputs (buttons) dont have a `placeholder` attribute

Comment: **If the error is** `INSERT command denied to user '***'@'localhost' for table 'rating''` Looks like you didnt setup the MySQL user account properly. Check who you are connecting as and then check that accounts privilages

Comment: I have checked with `show grants for user` and it tells me I am allowed to update on db.rating... @RiggsFolly

Comment: SImple test would be to connect with `root` and its password if you have set one. If it runs then, you know you made a woopsie when creating this other account

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am logging in as a "client" in the database and that triggers a procedure that creates his account privileges. I will try to manually create a "root" client and come back to you.

Comment: If you dont have access to the database as the `ROOT` (SUPERUSER) user, my above suggestion will not work.

Comment: Thats a reather odd way of doing things. Normally you would setup a single user with the required access and privilages and use that in your web site code to connect to a database.

Comment: @aynber Can you post your comment about `var_dump` as an answer so that I can close this question? I have added the `insert` privileges so now it works because I have had more information about what was the issue.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @tadman It is for an assignment for school. But thanks anyways. I did not know that.

Comment: Learning's great, but it's important to know what tools exist so you don't have to re-invent the wheel unless you're in a wheel-building class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having trouble finding out what was the problem with my code so I have tried using the infamous `echo` for debugging purpose. It wasn't successful so I had to ask for help.

```
if($result) {
    echo "Movie rated successfully!";
}
else {
    echo "Movie has not been rated...";
}
```

A helper told me to use this : **`echo var_dump($output->errorInfo())`** in case of `$result` being false;

I got the message that I was looking for :

                           `INSERT command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'rating'`

By going back to my database, I found that I granted the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` privileges to the user but not `INSERT`. ***That was the issue...***